# Evenness of Fourier coefficients implies even function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z})$ and let $F(n)$ denote its Fourier coefficients $$F(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx$$Assume that the Fourier coefficients determine an $L^1$ function.

How can we prove, **without** using Fourier transform, that if $F(n)=F(-n)$ for all $n$, then $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$?

Comment: You can't prove it for _all_ $x$, only for _almost all_, or that $f$ has an even representant. Can we use that $F(n) = 0$ for all $n$ implies $f = 0$ (almost everywhere)?

Comment: @DanielFischer Is the "$F(n)=0$ implies $f=0$ almost everywhere" a theorem? I haven't seen this fact before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x) = f(x) - f(-x)$. Then $\hat{g}(n) = \hat{f}(n) - \hat{f}(-n) = 0$ for all $n$. So by the uniqueness theorem $g(x) = 0$ a.e.

I'm not sure what you mean about not using the Fourier transform since the statement itself involves Fourier coefficients, but the usual proof of this uses convolutions and taking limits of them, with not much emphasis on the Fourier transform side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Zarrax. I saw a proof of this that mentions Fourier transform, which I haven't learned about, so I just wanted to avoid it. I would be interested in seeing your "usual proof of this uses convolutions and taking limits of them". (By the way, what uniqueness theorem are you using?)

Comment: It's in many harmonic analysis textbooks, and is just called the uniqueness theorem for Fourier series. It's in Katznelson's book in chapter $2$ for example. It uses that $f \ast K_n \rightarrow f$ in the $L^1$ norm, where $K_n$ is the Fejer kernel. Since $f \ast K_n = 0$ when the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are all zero, this means $f$, being the $L^1$ limit of the $f \ast K_n$, must also be $0$ a.e.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this satisfies the condition *not using Fourier transform*:
$$
\sum_{n=-N}^NF(n)\,e^{inx}=F(0)+\sum_{n=1}^NF(n)(e^{inx}+e^{-inx})=F(0)+2\sum_{n=1}^NF(n)\cos(n\,x).
$$
Since $\cos$ is an even function,...

Comment: Okay, but your term $\sum_{n=-N}^NF(n)e^{inx}$ doesn't represent the function $f(x)$. Even if you take the sum from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, it is not quite the same, is it?

Comment: You said that the $a_n$ determine an $L^1$ function. By uniqueness it must be $f$.

Comment: There could be infinitely many nonvanishing Fourier coefficients, and then the infinite sum might not converge to $f(x)$.